# How to automatically generate dynamic moment.js?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, momentjs

The idea would be to make one page a monthly table and each line would have week numbers and edit selection. For this I need moment.js and javascript to generate tables. Define the exact year and generate one table per month, week numbers, and the first day of the week.

I appreciate if you can help me with this.

Here we go jsfiddle and example.

- https://jsfiddle.net/n1039cme/1/

Example:

```css
.table-bordered {
    border: 1px solid #dee2e6;
}
.table-bordered thead td, .table-bordered thead th {
    border-bottom-width: 2px;
}
.table thead th {
    vertical-align: bottom;
    border-bottom: 2px solid #dee2e6;
}
.table-bordered td, .table-bordered th {
    border: 1px solid #dee2e6;
}
table.table thead th {
    border-top: none;
}
table.table td, table.table th {
    padding-top: 1.1rem;
    padding-bottom: 1rem;
}
.table td, .table th {
    padding: .75rem;
    vertical-align: top;
    border-top: 1px solid #dee2e6;
}
table td {
    font-size: .9rem;
    font-weight: 300;
}
```

```html
Generate 2019 (target) year months, week number and first day automatically with moment.js. I'm gonna use php to make tables dynamically.</p>

<table id="tablePreview" class="table table-hover table-bordered">
<!--Table head-->
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>January</th>
      <th>Week first day</th>
      <th>Last Name</th>
      <th>Username</th>
      <th>Edit</th>
     
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <!--Table head-->
  <!--Table body-->
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <th scope="row">Week number 1</th>
      <td>2019-01-01</td>
      <td>Otto</td>
      <td>@mdo</td>
      <td><a href="/edit-link.php">Edit</a></td>
   
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <th scope="row">Week number 2</th>
      <td>2019-01-01</td>
      <td>Thornton</td>
      <td>-</td>
      <td><a href="/edit-link.php">Edit</a></td>

    </tr>
    <tr>
      <th scope="row">Week number 3</th>
      <td>2019-01-01</td>
      <td>the Bird</td>
      <td>@twitter</td>
      <td><a href="/edit-link.php">Edit</a></td>

    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
<br><br>
<table id="tablePreview" class="table table-hover table-bordered">
<!--Table head-->
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>February</th>
      <th>Week first day</th>
      <th>Last Name</th>
      <th>Username</th>
      <th>Edit</th>
     
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <!--Table head-->
  <!--Table body-->
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <th scope="row">Week number 5</th>
      <td>2019-02-01</td>
      <td>Otto</td>
      <td>@mdo</td>
      <td><a href="/edit-link.php">Edit</a></td>
   
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <th scope="row">Week number 6</th>
      <td>2019-02-01</td>
      <td>Thornton</td>
      <td>-</td>
      <td><a href="/edit-link.php">Edit</a></td>

    </tr>
    <tr>
      <th scope="row">Week number 7</th>
      <td>2019-02-01</td>
      <td>the Bird</td>
      <td>@twitter</td>
      <td><a href="/edit-link.php">Edit</a></td>

    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
<p>
etc...
</p>
</p>
```

With moment.js this is all I have done..

```
var months = [];

for( var i = 0; i < 12; i++ ){
months.push( new Date(0,i).toLocaleString({},{month:'long'}) ); 
}

console.log(months);
```

Comment: Have you tried doing this yourself at all?

Comment: First post updated. I'm not good at javascript honestly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've quickly scribbled something together for you. This should be enough to get you going:

```
    var thisYear = 2018;
    var start = new Date("1/1/" + thisYear);
    var defaultStart = moment(start.valueOf());
    var weekNumber = 1;
    this.months = [];
    for (var i = 0; i < 12; i++) {
        var weeks = [];

        var currentMonth = defaultStart.month();

        var monthLimit = i + 1;

        if (defaultStart.month() == 11) {
            monthLimit = 0;
        }

        while (defaultStart.month() != monthLimit) {
            weeks.push(
                {
                    weekNumber: weekNumber,
                    firstDayOfWeek: defaultStart.format("MMM Do YYYY")
                }
            )
            weekNumber++;

            defaultStart.add(7, 'days')
        }
        this.months.push(
            {
                weeks: weeks,
                month: moment().month(currentMonth).format("MMMM")
            });
    }
```

This will create an array (the `months` array) for you of 12 objects; this object will contain the name of the month and an array of week objects, which consists of the week number and the first date of the week.

Take a look at [this](https://stackblitz.com/edit/typescript-d6zhm1) SlackBlitz example, where the table is displayed using the data generated in the code above using the [KnockOutJS](https://knockoutjs.com/) library.

Comment: Thanks a lot! Do you know how to make table so I can add data from mysql for these columns?

Comment: You'd want to add this into the weeks array; where I'm doing `weeks.push{object})`, you need to add your data to that object.

Comment: Can you give a example? If I add "edit" button every row (week array)

Comment: Well, if you want to continue using KnockOut (which I would recommend), then you'd add the button for each row. You won't need to add new items into the array, just add a new field into the html. Take a look at [this](https://stackblitz.com/edit/typescript-kztcvk) example SlackBlitz.